# Window forms - using timer to shrink rectangle vertically starting from bottom

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to figure how to use the timer to shrink the rectangle i draw on the window forms and shrink it from the bottom without changing the width of the rectangle, specifically i want to reduce its height from the bottom of the rectangle to the top of the rectangle. So far i can only increase its size, so im stuck with decreasing its size from the bottom up.

```
    static int size = 195;

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g = this.CreateGraphics();

        //This is the rectangle i want to reduce its height from bottom up
        g.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(115, 205, 20, size));

         //the height decreasing one by one as the timer is started
         size--: 
    }
```